# angular service jasmine test can't find $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, jasmine

Following the tutorial here: http://www.benlesh.com/2013/06/angular-js-unit-testing-services.html the following jasmine test should work -- but doesn't.  I've reduced the test down to the simplest possible thing to test.  Unlike the example test I linked, I can't get this to pass.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

The service under test:

```js
var appServices = angular.module('MyApp.services', ['$http', '$rootScope']);
  appServices.factory('Auth', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {

    var accessLevels = routingConfig.accessLevels,
        userRoles = routingConfig.userRoles,
        currentUser = { username: '', role: userRoles.public };

    function changeUser(user) {
        angular.extend(currentUser, user);
    }

    return {
        authorize: function (accessLevel, role) {
            if (role === undefined) {
                role = currentUser.role;
            }
            return accessLevel.bitMask & role.bitMask;
        },
        isLoggedIn: function (user) {
            if (user === undefined) {
                user = currentUser;
            }
            return user.role.title === userRoles.user.title;
        },
        login: function (user, success, error) { //ignore jslint
            user.role = userRoles.user;
            changeUser(user);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('login');
            success(user);
        },
        logout: function (success, error) { //ignore jslint
            changeUser({
                username: '',
                password: '',
                role: userRoles.public
            });
            success();
        },
        accessLevels: accessLevels,
        userRoles: userRoles,
        user: currentUser
    };
}]);
```

The test:

```js
describe('services tests', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('MyApp.services');

        // get your service, also get $httpBackend
        // $httpBackend will be a mock, thanks to angular-mocks.js
        inject(function (_Auth_, $httpBackend) {
            Auth = _Auth_;
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        });
    });
    it('should have an authorize function', function () {
        expect(angular.isFunction(Auth.authorize)).toBe(true);
    });

});
```

The error message:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp.services due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module $http due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module '$http' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$injector/nomod?p0=%24http
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:78:12
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:1531:17
    at ensure (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:1456:38)
    at module (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:1529:14)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:3632:22
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:304:11)
    at loadModules (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:3626:5)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:3633:40
    at Array.forEach (native)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var appServices = angular.module('MyApp.services', ['$http', '$rootScope']);`

should be

`var appServices = angular.module('MyApp.services', []);`

`$http` and `$rootScope` are not modules so the error was `appServices` could not find `$http` module.